# Presentations of superperfect groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, presentations-of-groups

Are there non-trivial superperfect groups with the property that there exists a presentation of the group where the number of generators equals the number of relations?

Comment: Superperfect means 1st and 2nd homology vanish (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superperfect_group). In other words, trivial abelianization and trivial Schur multiplier

Answer (score 8):

Yes, for example ${\rm SL}(2,5) \cong \langle a,b \mid a^2=b^{-3}=(ab)^5 \rangle$.

Furthermore, it is proved in:

C.M. Campbell and E.F. Robertson,
``A deficiency zero presentation for ${\rm SL}(2,p)$'',
Bull. Lon. Math. Soc. 12 (1980) 17-20,

that, when $p$ is an odd prime and $k = \lfloor p/3 \rfloor$, then

$$\langle \,x,y \mid x^2(xy)^{-3},\, (xy^4xy^{(p+1)/2})^2y^px^{2k}
\,\,\rangle \cong {\rm SL}(2,p).$$

Comment: Just as a consequence, the free product of n copies of any of these ones

Answer (score 4):

For $M$ a closed, connected, orientable 3-manifold, it's well known that the existence of a Heegaard splitting for $M$ implies that the fundamental group $\pi_1M$ admits a balanced presentation (i.e. one with as many generators as relations).

Any such $M$ splits as a connect sum of irreducible pieces $M_i$, meaning that every embedded 2-sphere in the $M_i$ bounds a 3-ball.  It follows from the Sphere theorem that $\pi_1M$ is superperfect if and only if $M$ is a homology sphere.

This leads to many examples. The most well known is the Poincare homology sphere (whose fundamental group is $SL(2,5)$, as in Derek Holt's answer), but there are infinitely many others: see [Ryan Budney's answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4799/1463) for a nice summary.